# SonarQube Local Analysis - specify properties file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to run the analysis locally using Sonar-Scanner 2.6 pointing to SonarQube 5.4. The local solution folder contains the *sonar-project.properties* file used in the cloud analysis.

I am trying to create the properties file to be used locally, that is separate from the global *sonar-project.properties* file. This is the command that I ran:

```
sonar-scanner -D project.settings=sonar-project-local.properties
```

Expected behavior: Of the two files (*sonar-project.properties* and *sonar-project-local.properties*), sonar-scanner would choose the local one.

Observed behavior: If the file *sonar-project.properties* exists, sonar-scanner uses the global one and ignores the local one.

If I remove (rename) the global file from the directory, then the local file is recognized, and behavior is as expected.

Is this a bug? What is the way to solve this issue without messing with the global properties file?

Answer (score 4):

Generally the answer would be the space in your command. So, not

```
-D project.settings=...
```

but

```
-Dproject.settings=...
```

But that property was dropped. You'll just need to shuffle the properties files in/out of the "correct" name.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but with or without the space, the result is the same in all scenarios..

Comment: I double-checked everything - spelling, arguments, spaces, tried using quotes and relative/absolute paths.. I also know that the cmd argument works, because if I remove sonar-project.properties file, only leave sonar-project-local.properties file and run the analysis with the argument, scanner picks it up. If I run it without the argument - it doesn't.

Comment: @worldpart that is indeed another question. Please post it separately. :)

Comment: [Done!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533015/asp-net-and-sonarlint)