# ASP .NET and SonarLint

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, sonarqube, sonarlint

We have an ASP .NET project, we are trying to have an on-the-fly analysis of JS. SonarLint only provides the analysis of C# files.. Incremental analysis seems to have been deprecated, and issues analysis requires different configuration files, which SonarQube Scanner does not support. Having 2 different configuration files and continuously renaming them is, as you can imagine, is a very difficult task to convince, educate, and discipline a large team of developers to do.. What would be the solution?

Comment: Not sure to have properly understood your question. Are you talking about the quality profiles?

Comment: Not quite, SonarQube in the cloud analyses all of the files. I am talking about local, pre-commit analysis on the fly, just as the developer is writing the code. SonarLint does that (underlines the issues) right in the Visual Studio, but only for C#. I am looking for a solution that will be suitable for JavaScript development. I have tried Incremental Analysis, but it was deprecated, along with many other things that used to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (for now) have on-the-fly support of JS within SonarLint for Visual Studio but you can have some with IntelliJ/Eclipse although I am not sure the experience would be that great for a ASP.Net Project.

What I would suggest, if you really want to have the analysis before your commit, is to have a local SonarQube server (can be found [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)) and manually run the [Scanner for CLI](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line) and to push result to this local instance.

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit, it seems like a tough task to get everyone on the team local sonar servers... What about just using SonarScanner and Issues Report? I am having trouble running incremental analysis on it though, as it was sort of replaced by "issues" analysis, and connecting the scanner to the server does not do much, as the report still shows all issues as new. Moreover, I have trouble with exclusions - although they are specified within the properties file, they don't work...